# How to create dynamic variables in Python 3

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.4

I am trying to get values from a Tkinter `Entry()` widget, but it returns that `str() has no attribute get()`:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import * 
root=Tk()
flag=0
a={'x','y','z'}  # Consider these as columns in database
for i in a:
    i=Entry(root)
    i.pack()
def getter():
    for i in a:
        b=i.get()  # i is read as string and not as variable                    
        print(b)
asdf=Button(root,text='Enter',command=getter)
asdf.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I do variable variables in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-do-variable-variables-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is the problem:

```
def getter():
    for i in a:
        b=i.get()     #i is read as string and not as variable
```

`a` is a set comprised of three strings. When you iterate over it, `i` will be a string. Therefore, when you call `i.get()` you're trying to call `.get()` on a string.

One solution is to store your entry widgets in a list, so you can iterate over that instead:

```
widgets = []
for i in a:
    i=Entry(root)
    i.pack()
    widgets.append(i)
...
for i in widgets:
    b=i.get()
    ...
```

If you want the widgets to be associated with the letters, use a dictionary:

```
widgets = {}
for i in a:
    i=Entry(root)
    i.pack()
    widgets[a] = i
...
for i in a:
    b=widgets[i].get()
```

Comment: Thanks Bryan, I got the exact answer i wanted , very nice first experience on Stackoverflow.